# Silverlight 4.0: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application[Async_ExceptionOccured]

Tags: silverlight, deployment, silverlight-4.0

I am deploying my Silverlight 4.0 application in various operating system.
In Windows 7 it works perfectly, however in Windows XP SP3, error pops. It says Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application [Async_ExceptionOccurred] Arguments: Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.50524.0&File=System.dll&Key=Async_ExceptionOccurred....

What seems could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Not really much useful information to go on here.  Note only is there no code but we don't even know what type async operation is being performed.

Comment: By what is written I guess this the error is from the deployment server and this application works fine when debugging. So I bet the ServiceReference has hardcoded http://localhost:port/path in it, thats why it doesn't work on the development server.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, the reason behind code is not displayed because the installer works in windows 7 but not in XP.

Comment: Installer? Please get your facts straight, we are trying to help, but you give us info that makes no sense

Answer (score 5):

Go to the client bin folder and rename your `.xap` file to `.zip`.  You should now be able to open the file up like any normal zip file.  Locate the `.clientconfig` file and open it up in Notepad.  Check that your endpoint addresses are set to a FQDN.

Comment: saved me big time on this one.

Comment: Saved me hours too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your Silverlight project locate the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` file and open it.

in Silverlight 4 you can address your endpoints with `..` like this:

```
 <endpoint address="../Services/Common.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" contract="Common.ICommon"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommon" />
```